# Show Job's Log Messages between Event ID's N and N

Tags: monitoring, datastage, ibm-infosphere

Is there a way to show specific job's log message events using their event ID's?

For example, you can:

> ./dsjob -lognewest Project Job

And it will give you the latest Event ID - for example:

> Newest id = 3270

You can limit the extracted Event ID's messages with:

> ./dsjob -logsum -max 30 Project Job

How can I show only the messages of Event ID's between N and N ID?

If not - is there a way to check how many times one job run on a specific date?

Comment: No - as far as I know - but you could do some post-processing using grep etc.

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher: Thanks, Michael! I've updated my question - if not - is there a way to check how many times one job run on a specific date?

Comment: This is a easy thing using an alternative interface. I suggest you check out DSODB this is a data model in a DB that allows to get lots of operational meta data (SQL).

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher: Thanks, Michael - an exemplary SQL query would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out the documentation here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.monitor.doc/topics/queryodb.html

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher Thanks! I know this - regrettably, we still use ver. 8.5 which does not support such queries - in this useful way, I mean.